# How can I align some text left and keep some text centered on the same line?

Tags: css

I have a button with text `Create Group` on it which, when clicked, turns into a `Cancel` button.  To keep things visually consistent, both buttons will have the same width.  Both also have a font-awesome icon to the left like so:

[image]

I want the icon for both buttons to be left-aligned, while the text is center aligned, so the finished product should look like this:

[image]

I tried floating the icon left, but that also had the unintended affect of moving it up vertically.  I can add `position: relative` and an arbitrary `top: 2px` I guess, but that seems pretty hacky for what should be simple.

```css
button {
  width: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create Group
</button>

<button type="button">
  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancel
</button>
```

Comment: you could use position absolute on the icon and text-align center the text

Answer (score 1):

You can use positioning to do this:

```
button {
  width: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hjvaezp5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it works:

```
button{
width: 110px;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

i{
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
```